# Отправка GET-запроса

Tags: http, rust

Пытаюсь отправить get-запрос на сайт через requests, но вылезает ошибка:

```
PS D:\failes\все\scripts\rust2\MyProgram> cargo run
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `security-framework = "^0.1.9"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 2.7.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `native-tls v0.1.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `native-tls = "^0.1"` of package `hyper-native-tls v0.2.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `hyper-native-tls = "^0.2"` of package `requests v0.0.28`
    ... which satisfies dependency `requests = "^0.0.28"` of package `MyProgram v0.1.0 (D:\failes\все\scripts\rust2\MyProgram)`
```

**main.rs**

```
extern crate requests;
use requests::ToJson;

fn main() {
    let response = requests::get("http://httpbin.org/get").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(response.url(), "http://httpbin.org/get");
    assert_eq!(response.reason(), "OK");
    assert_eq!(response.status_code(), requests::StatusCode::Ok);

    let data = response.json().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(data["url"], "http://httpbin.org/get");
    assert_eq!(data["headers"]["Host"], "httpbin.org");
    assert_eq!(data["headers"]["User-Agent"],
               concat!("requests-rs/", env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")));
}
```

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "MyProgram"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]



requests = "0.0.30"
```

Пытался искать решение в интернете, но ничего не нашел.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Это какой-то старый крейт (2017 года). Используйте https://crates.io/crates/reqwest

Comment: @vessd Большое тебе спасибо